# User authentication does login without authenticating

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am trying to do  a simple "User Authentication" in cakephp. I wrote code as given in cook book but my login function is not working properly.
It does not do any authentication and allows any user to access or edit data and even when provided with blank username and password, allows me to login.I have written the following code in Appcontroller.php

```
<?php
class AppController extends Controller {

public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
         'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'index'),
         'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'login')
        )
    );
   public function beforeFilter() {
       $this->layout = 'admin_layout';
       $this->Auth->allow('index','view'); 

        }
```

UsersController.php

```
    <?php

    App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
    App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');

    class UsersController extends AppController {


        public function login() 
            {

                if($this->request->is('post')) {
                    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                        if($this->Auth->login());
                       $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
                    } else {
                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
                    }

            }}
            public function logout() {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
        }

Login.ctp is as follows



 <?php echo $this->Html->css('login');?>
    <div class="logincontainer">

    <div class="loginform">
    <div class="img">
    </div>


    <?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
    <div id="input">
    <div id="username">
      <?php // echo $this->Form->input('username');?>

     <?php echo $this->Form->input('username',array('class'=>'name','placeholder'=>'username','label'=>false));?>
    </div>
    <div id="space">
    </div>
    <div id="password">
        <?php //     echo $this->Form->input('password');?> 
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('password',array('class'=>'name','placeholder'=>'password','label'=>false));?>
    </div>
        <div id="space1"></div>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end('Login'); ?>

        <div id="forgot">Forgot Password

            </div>
    </div>
        <?php // echo $this->Session->flash();?>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Can somebody please guide as to where I am wrong..

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't login but redirect to index action and you think login beacuse your loginRedirect option is index action and you allow this action in beforeFilter

```
$this->Auth->allow('index','view');
```

please add:

```
debug($this->Auth->login());
debug($this->request->data);
die();
```

before:

```
if ($this->Auth->login()) {
    if($this->Auth->login());
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
} else {
     $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
}
```

result of debug($this->Auth->login()); should be false if you enter wrong user or password